# Web search listing all matches in its index

Tags: web, search, text-search

My basic use case is filtering search results based on a broad category the result should or should not belong to. Examples of categories are news, online stores, fora, scientific articles, personal pages... I have a program that classifies a given site based on its content. The only thing I need is a list of search results to narrow down. But common search engines give just a few results that they consider relevant themselves, while I need to go through this selection process myself.

One example use case: I was looking for online discussion of Ilya Prigogine's book "Order Out of Chaos", but all search engines kept returning places to buy the book, encyclopedia articles about the author, or big sites like Goodreads.

Another use case: finding usage of a word or phrase "in the wild". For many phrases, standard search engines return lots of dictionaries giving example sentences, but what I'm looking for is purely incidental usage of the given word (this is useful in learning a foreign language). I can automatically decide (with sufficient accuracy) whether a site is a dictionary, but I haven't found any way of getting Google to give me anything else. Merely adding -"dictionary" to the query doesn't work, see for example [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22loquacious%22%20-%22dictionary%22%20-%22definition%22) (my top result is Wiktionary). This also happens on [Duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=loquacious%20-dictionary%20-definition&va=v&t=ha&ia=web), [Qwant](https://www.qwant.com/?q=loquacious%20-dictionary%20-definition&t=web), and every other alternative I've ever tried.

What I would like is to get a big list of URLs leading to sites where a given string occurs, then go through that list using a combination of manual and automated methods for filtering some results out. This is all done on my side, so **all I need is the initial list of URLs**. In fact, in some cases, what I'm looking for might not exist, but in that case I want to know that I've exhausted the possibilities.

Standard search engines provide a selection of the actual string matches based on some unknown criteria. There is no such thing as a Google Search manual, so we're in the dark about its inner workings. The same goes for Duckduckgo, Qwant, etc. The best I could find was [Qwant's vague description for legal purposes](https://about.qwant.com/en/legal/classement/) (emphasis mine):

> The classification of results during a search is carried out automatically **by an algorithm**, by default according to the relevance of the contents calculated in a relative way through a **multitude of criteria**. These criteria include in particular **the presence, frequency, emphasis and context of the keywords searched for in the page content, the age of the page, the popularity of the site on which the page is present, or the legibility and accessibility of the page**. No commercial agreement influences the calculation of relevance and therefore the ranking of a page in the search results.

I'm looking for a dumb string match. The priorities in descending order of importance:

- No filtering of results based on anything besides the query, the coverage in the index, and possibly a cutoff if there are too many matches.
- Coverage of as much of the World Wide Web as possible.
- A reasonably powerful query language. Searching for exact strings of words would be very good, as would a way to actually exclude

I don't mind if the query takes a long time to process or if there is a rate limit. Paid services are fine as well if they fulfill the criteria above.